# Should the namespace defined in the XML be declared in the XSLT as well for the transformation to be successful?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL which matches all attributes from the input XML and copies them as it is into the output XML. I use the `name()` function to get the name of the matched attribute. 
When the XSL encounters an attribute whose namespace is not defined in the XSL itself I get a "Unknown Schema Prefix" error. But when I define these namespaces inside the XSL it works fine.

Why is this definition of namespaces necessary?

Comment: If you're just copying the attributes unchanged, why use `name()`? Are you trying to strip the prefixes? If so, try `local-name()`.

Comment: i don't strip the prefixes. i just copy the name as it is and then do some conditional copying of the value of the attribute. if i use local-name() then i will lose the namespace in the output XML which i don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want us to tell you what's wrong with your code, it helps to show your code. Otherwise we just have to guess. My guess would be that you are doing something like:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
```

which will fail if `name()` returns something like "***xyz***:banana" where **xyz** is not a prefix declared in the stylesheet. The better way to do this is:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>
```

But if I've completely mis-guessed the problem, then - blame yourself.